# How to fix the error property doesnt exist with type never[] using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have data like below,

```
{main: {}}
```

within main I have object data like below

```
main {
    id: '1',
    main_1: [
        {
            id: '1',
            main_2: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    data: [ 
                        { //want to retrieve this
                            id: '1',
                            version: '1.1',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: '2',
                            version: '1.1',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            main_2: [
                {
                    id: '3',
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: '3',
                            version: '1.1',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: '4',
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: '4',
                            version: '1.1',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

as seen from above data object, i want to retrieve the first main_1 and get its first main_2 and get first main_2 data.

i was trying to use code like below,

```
function Parent() {
    const main = get(data, 'main');
    const main_1 = main && main.main_1 ? main.main_1 : [];
    const first_main_2 = main_1 && main_1[0] && main_1[0].main_2[0] ? 
        main_1[0].main_2[0] : [];

    const data = first_main_2 && first_main_2.data; // error here property data 
    //doesnt exist on type never[]
    const version =
        (first_main_2 &&
            data &&
                data.find(
                    (item: itemVersion) => item.id === data.id //error here 
                    //property id doesnt exist on type never[]
        )) || {};
  

    return (
        <span>{getSomeFunction(version.version)}</span>
    );  
}
```

The above code gives me error like below

**property data doesnt exist on type never[].
property id doesnt exist on type never[].**

not sure why it is causing this error. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be accessed with `main.main_1[0].main_2[0].data`

[image]

Comment: thanks yes. but i have done it with the snippet as seen in my question and gives me error property doesnt exist in type never[]